# Is it possible to hide or show links in laravel after login

Tags: php, laravel, session, hide, show

I am new to Laravel. I am now able to register users, log them in. But after login, I don't want to display register and login pages. I want to display logout link. This is easy for me with core php.
I want something similar like the one below.

```
<?php
  if(isset($_SESSION['id'])){
      ?>
      <a href="index.php">Home</a>
      <a href="dashboard.php">Dashboard</a>
      <a href="logout.php">Logout</a>
      <?php
  }else{
      ?>
      <a href="index.php">Home</a>
      <a href="register.php">Register</a>
      <a href="login">Login</a>   
      <?php
  }
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@if(Auth::user())
<button>I'm logged in</button>
@else
<button>I'm not logged in </button>
@endif
```

Answer (score 0):

Blade has @auth, which checks if user is logged in or not

```
@auth
/* what logged in users should see */
@else
/* what guests should see */
@endauth
```

Also has @guest (ending with @endguest) which does the opposite.

And if you named your routes, you can for example:

```
href="{{route('login')}}"
```

This way the url changes if you change your routes.

Answer (score 0):

This is How I did it. It's working though, but I don't know if it's the right way.

```
 @if(!Session::has('users')
   <a href="">Home</a>
   <a href="">Register</a>
   <a href="">Login</a>
 @elseif(Session::has('users')
   <a href="">Home</a>
   <a href="">Dasboard</a>
   <a href="">Logout</a>
 @ndif
```

'users' is the user id as the Session variable from database